# Inheriting from instance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, instance, overloading

In Python, I would like to construct an instance of the Child's class directly from an instance of the Parent class. For example:

```
A = Parent(x, y, z)
B = Child(A)
```

This is a hack that I thought might work:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        print "INITILIZING PARENT"
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Child(Parent):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        print "NEW'ING CHILD"
        if len(args) == 1 and str(type(args[0])) == "<class '__main__.Parent'>":
            new_args = []
            new_args.extend([args[0].x, args[0].y, args[0].z])
            print "HIJACKING"
            return Child(*new_args)
        print "RETURNING FROM NEW IN CHILD"
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwds)
```

But when I run

```
B = Child(A)
```

I get:

```
NEW'ING CHILD  
HIJACKING  
NEW'ING CHILD  
RETURNING FROM NEW IN CHILD  
INITILIZING PARENT  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "classes.py", line 52, in <module>  
    B = Child(A)  
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

It seems the hack works just as I expected but the compiler throws a TypeError at the end. I  was wondering if I could overload TypeError to make it ignore the B = Child(A) idiom but I wasn't sure how to do that. In any case, would you please give me your solutions for inheriting from instances?

Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI, "initializing" is spelled with an 'a' in it. Tried editing this but StackOverflow won't allow edits less than 6 letters.

Answer (score 13):

I find this (encapsulation) to be the cleanest way:

```
class Child(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = Parent()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)
```

This way you can use all Parent's method and your own without running into the problems of inheritance.

Comment: After trying all options here, this is definitely the solution I was looking for. Cleanest, easiest, never have to know variable names. Highly recommend.

Answer (score 10):

OK, so I didn't realize that you where happy with a static copy of the arguments until I was already halfway done with my solution. But I decided not to waste it, so here it is anyway. The difference from the other solutions is that it will actually get the attributes from the parent even if they updated.

```
_marker = object()

class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Child(Parent):

    _inherited = ['x', 'y', 'z']

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self.a = "not got from dad"

    def __getattr__(self, name, default=_marker):
        if name in self._inherited:
            # Get it from papa:
            try:
                return getattr(self._parent, name)
            except AttributeError:
                if default is _marker:
                    raise
                return default

        if name not in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError(name)
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

Now if we do this:

```
>>> A = Parent('gotten', 'from', 'dad')
>>> B = Child(A)
>>> print "a, b and c is", B.x, B.y, B.z
a, b and c is gotten from dad

>>> print "But x is", B.a
But x is not got from dad

>>> A.x = "updated!"
>>> print "And the child also gets", B.x
And the child also gets updated!

>>> print B.doesnotexist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "acq.py", line 44, in <module>
    print B.doesnotexist
  File "acq.py", line 32, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: doesnotexist
```

For a more generic version of this, look at the http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Acquisition package. It is in fact, in some cases a bloody need solution.

Answer (score 8):

Once `__new__` in class `Child` returns an instance of `Child`, `Child.__init__` will be called (with the same arguments `__new__` was given) on that instance -- and apparently it just inherits `Parent.__init__`, which does not take well to being called with just one arg (the other `Parent`, `A`).

If there is no other way a `Child` can be made, you can define a `Child.__init__` that accepts either one arg (which it ignores) or three (in which case it calls `Parent.__init__`).  But it's simpler to forego `__new__` and have all the logic in `Child.__init__`, just calling the `Parent.__init__` appropriately!

To make this concrete with a code example:

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        print "INITIALIZING PARENT"
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r, %r)" % (self.__class__.__name__,
            self.x, self.y, self.z)


class Child(Parent):

    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self, x, y=_sentinel, z=_sentinel):
        print "INITIALIZING CHILD"
        if y is self._sentinel and z is self._sentinel:
            print "HIJACKING"
            z = x.z; y = x.y; x = x.x
        Parent.__init__(self, x, y, z)
        print "CHILD IS DONE!"

p0 = Parent(1, 2, 3)
print p0
c1 = Child(p0)
print c1
c2 = Child(4, 5, 6)
print c2
```

Comment: Anyone else find confusing the use of a sentinel? That muddles the signature of `Child.__init__`. I would find much more understandable `def __init__(self, *args)` followed by `if len(args) == 1: parent, = args` `...` `elif len(args) == 3: x, y, z = args` `...`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't define a constructor (init) for Child, so the Parent constructor is called, expecting 4 arguments while only 2 are passed in (from new).  Here's one way to accomplish what you want:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], Parent):
            Parent.__init__(self, args[0].x, args[0].y, args[0].z)

        else:
            # do something else
```

Comment: +1: Simply create a Child by copying attributes of the parent.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an extremely old thread, but I recently ran into the same challenge as Alexandra, and this was the most relavent topic I could find. I had a parent class with many, many attributes, and I wanted to essentially 'patch' an instance of it, by keeping all of its methods and attributes, adding a few, and modifying/overwriting others. A simple subclass wouldn't work because the attributes would be filled in by the user during runtime, and I couldn't just inherit the default values from the parent class. After a lot of tinkering I found a very clean (though rather hacky) way to do it by using `__new__`. Here's an example:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # whatever you want here
        self.x = 42
        self.y = 5
    def f(self):
        print "Parent class, x,y =", self.x, self.y

class Child(Parent):
    def __new__(cls, parentInst):
        parentInst.__class__ = Child
        return parentInst
    def __init__(self, parentInst):
        # You don't call the Parent's init method here
        self.y = 10
    def f(self):
        print "Child class, x,y =", self.x, self.y

c = Parent()
c.f()  # Parent class, x,y = 42 5
c.x = 13
c.f()  # Parent class, x,y = 13 5
c = Child(c)
c.f()  # Child class, x,y = 13 10
```

The only special part is changing the `__class__` attribute of the Parent class in the Child's constructor. Because of this, the Child's `__init__` method will be called as usual, and to my knowledge the Child class should function exactly as any other inherited class.

Comment: I also ran into something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177788/init-child-with-parent-instance

Comment: This kind of works. But you could only have one instance of the Child class based on the same Parent. If there were multiple Children with the same Parent, the Children would all modify each other's variables.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, guys, that was quick! I first read Alex's comment and I rewrote the Child's `__init__` as

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
    if len(args) == 1 and str(type(args[0])) == "<class '__main__.Parent'>":
        new_args = [args[0].x, args[0].y, args[0].z]
        super(Child, self).__init__(*new_args, **kwds)
    else:
        super(Child, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
```

which is very similar to what abhinavg suggested (as I just found out). And it works. Only his  and ars' line

```
if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], Parent):
```

is cleaner than mine.

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old thread, but I hope future readers will still benefit from the simple solution I have found.

A very simple way to get the **init** values of an instance is to use the vars() function. It returns the **dict** attribute of an object (returns the class/instance attributes). I find this approach more readable than messing with **new**, and it handles any amount of attributes.

```
class Parent(object): 
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, **kwargs):
        # kwargs is not necessary but
        # it handles if too many variables are given
        print("Accessing Parent")
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, instance):
        print("Child")
        instance_attrs = vars(instance)
        super().__init__(**instance_attrs)
        # Parent.__init__(self, **instance_attrs)
A = Parent(x, y, z)
# Accessing Parent
print(vars(A))
# {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z}
B = Child(A)
# Child
# Accessing Parent
print(A.x, B.x) 
# x x
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope not to be away from the subject, because i'm quite specific but it's the only related question i found.

If you want inherit attribute that are from a parent object through composition, and without copying any value you can do this:

```
class Agro:
    def __init__(self, parent, prop1=None, prop2=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self._prop1 = prop1
        self._prop2 = prop2

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        try:
            if self._prop1 is None:
                return self.parent.prop1
            else:
                return self._prop1
        except AttributeError as e:
            return None

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        try:
            if self._prop2 is None:
                return self.parent.prop2
            else:
                return self._prop2
        except AttributeError as e:
            return None
```

Then you instanciate:

```
ag = Agro(None, prop1="nada")  # prop1: nada, prop2: None
ag2 = Agro(ag, prop1="nada2")  # prop1: nada2, prop2: None
ag3 = Agro(ag2, prop2="youhou")  # prop1: nada2, prop2: youhou
ag4 = Agro(ag3)  # prop1: nada2, prop2: youhou
```

What's interesting is when you look at what is actually saved in the instances with `__dict__` attributes are only saved once. You can therefore modify dynamically the attributes value:

```
ag3._prop2 = "yaya"
print(ag4.prop2)  # yaya
```