# __getattr__ unexpectedly updates instance of a non-inherited class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to replicate the API of a Java library for a vehicle routing problem and it's highlighted something I don't understand about Python classes.

A vehicle fleet can be broken down into two basic criteria; the first is the types of vehicle you own (instances of `VehicleType` to define capacities, running costs etc.) and individual vehicles (`Vehicle` with different shift patterns etc.).

In my simplified example, I want to define one `VehicleType` and then a single `Vehicle` that takes the attributes of the `VehicleType` passed to the constructor. Following the answer by Lennart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081253/inheriting-from-instance-in-python), using `__getattr__` works perfectly in a general case. However, imagine that I have a driver of one van out of 50 that has a special qualification to carry something hazardous, so I want to add an extra capacity property on the *`Vehicle`* instance. I tried the following:

```
class VehicleType(object):

    def __init__(self, fixed_cost=0, cost_per_distance=0, cost_per_time=0):
        self.capacities = {}
        self.fixed_cost = fixed_cost
        self.cost_per_distance = cost_per_distance
        self.cost_per_time = cost_per_time

    def add_capacity_dimension(self, dimension_id, dimension_size):
        """ Define a package type and how many of them this vehicle type can carry """
        self.capacities[dimension_id] = dimension_size


class Vehicle(object):

    def __init__(self, vehicle_type=None, identifier=None):
        self._vehicle_type = vehicle_type
        self.identifier = identifier

    def add_capacity_dimension(self, dimension_id, dimension_size):
        self.capacities[dimension_id] = dimension_size

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._vehicle_type, name) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    van_type = VehicleType()
    van_type.add_capacity_dimension("general items", 34)

    special_van = Vehicle(vehicle_type=van_type)
    special_van.add_capacity_dimension("hazardous chemicals", 50)

    print("Capacities of special van: {}".format(special_van.capacities))
    print("Capacity of van_type:      {}".format(van_type.capacities)) # Why?
```

I don't understand why my approach has also affected the `capacities` of the `van_type`. `Vehicle` does not directly inherit from `VehicleType` and I have defined `add_capacity_dimension` within the `Vehicle` class. This also contradicts my understanding of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) about `__getattr__`:

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the
>   usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in
>   the class tree for self). name is the attribute name.

Can someone please explain why the instance `van_type` is also affected here?

Comment: What part of this surprises you? Are you surprised that `van_type` has a `capacities`? Are you surprised that it was mutated?

Comment: @user2357112 You are correct, I missed the link from looking too long. `capacities` for `Vehicle` requires `__getattr__` in itself. In that case, is the only way to do this to define `capacities` within `Vehicle` and then have `__getattr__` for the rest of the attributes?

Comment: @roganjosh  They **will** match.  If they don't, then your MCVE is wrong.

Comment: @wim MCVE is correct, I validated `id()` wrong while trying to write it. Checked again. Thanks guys, sorry for the <facepalm> moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vehicle` instances don't have a "capacities" attribute.

The `self.capacities` attribute lookup on the `special_van` (from within `Vehicle.add_capacity_dimension` implementation) is resolved not on the  `Vehicle` but on the `VehicleType`, via the custom `__getattr__`.

Therefore, `special_van.capacities` and `van_type.capacities` are the same dict.