# Inherit from Instance rather than Class [Python 3]

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

I am wanting to initiate multiple instances of a sub classes that each take their attributes from a specific instance of a class, rather than the general class.

For example if I have buildings and rooms, every room needs to belong to a specific instance of a building, taking its attributes and methods.

```
class Building:
     def __init__(self, buildingName, location):
        self.buildingName = buildingName
        self.location = location
        # lots more intersting stuff

    def Evacuate_Building(self):
        # do some stuff
        pass

class Room(Building):
     def __init__(self, roomName, roomType):
        self.roomName = roomName
        self.roomType = roomType
        # lots more intersting stuff

    def Directions(self, Current_Location):
        '''do some stuff involving this.roomName and this.location which comes from the specific instance of the class'''
        pass
```

So say I have three buildings: 'North', 'South' and 'West'.

Each building has its own rooms.

Looking at just the North Building it has the rooms 'N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4'.

In my code I would go through and initiate the three Buildings first, then I would initiate the Rooms, some how linking them back to its corresponding Building.

This allows me to use the Directions method, which utalises the attribute location from its parent class instance, which is unique to that Building, not a general value. It also needs to be be able to use the method from the parent class, Evacuate_Building.

I could get around this by passing the location data every time I initiate a room in the more standard setup using super(buildingName, location) or Building.__ init__(self, buildingName, location) however this means I have to write the location for every single Room and if I add or change something in the Building, I need to change every single room initialisation and the init code if additional attributes have been added.

I can also copy a the attributes out by passing the instance of the Building as a parameter to the init and then going this.location = building.location but this also has the same problems as above plus I do not get the methods this way.

I want some way of passing the specific instance of the Building, so that the room inherits its specific attributes and its methods.

Any feedback, suggestions, criticism, completely different ways of doing this is welcome! **Thank you in advance!**

Comment: I do not think python have so called passing specific instance of Building. Instead, you can create a sub function for building to generate rooms, and an attribute called self.rooms. And another function change_location, when you call change_location for building  function, it change the location of all rooms under his attribute.

Comment: Once built, a `Building` hardly changes location, and a `Room` hardly changes `Building` @Marcus.Aurelianus

Comment: @Reblochon Masque, basically i am answering 'if I add or change something in the Building, I need to change every single room initialisation and the init code if additional attributes have been added.', it can be another attribute of the building. I admit I am wrong in location.

Comment: It’s worth noting that what you’re asking for isn’t what you want here, and is in fact very rarely what you want, but it’s not incoherent for some designs. It’s called _prototype inheritance_ rather than _class inheritance_. And it is possible to do it in Python, you just have to build the whole mechanism yourself, rather than using the functionality built into the language. But no major language other than JavaScript does prototype inheritance, and that JS developers have spent decades trying to build class inheritance into their language, because classes fit your object model much more often

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus: Sounds like the correct solution is to have the building have attributes, and the rooms have a reference to the building containing them. `__getattr__` can then be used to make attribute access on `Room` for attributes that don't exist pull data from its building seamlessly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, you are right. Forget about __getattr__, I am also new to python...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your design is very weird. A room is not a building, so why should `Room` inherit from `Building`?<sup>1</sup>

There *is* a relationship between rooms and buildings: every room is in a building, and every building contains zero or more rooms. You can represent either relationship, or both,<sup>2</sup> by *composition*—that is, by adding members:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, building, roomName, roomType):
        self.building = building
        self.roomName = roomName
        self.roomType = roomType
        # lots more intersting stuff
```

Or:

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, buildingName, location):
        self.buildingName = buildingName
        self.location = location
        self.rooms = set()
    def add(self, room):
        self.rooms.add(room)
```

You could even make `Room.__init__` call `building.add(self)` if you wanted.

---

Notice that this gives you exactly what you wanted: each `Room` is related to a specific `Building` instance, `self.building`, instead of to the `Building` class.

So, you don't have to write the location for every single `Room`, you just pass the same `Building` instance to all of them. And if I add or change something in the `Building`, every `Room` in that building will see that change in its `self.building` without you having to repeat yourself or do anything special.

And not even just statically in the code. You can move a `Building` at runtime with `self.location = new_location`. Then, for every `Room` in that `Building`, its `self.building.location` is now `new_location`.

---

Also, you wouldn't normally want a `Room` to support the methods of a `Building`. Calling `Evacuate_Building` on a `Room` doesn't make much sense. Calling `Evacuate_Room` might. In which case your `Building` might do something like this:

```
def Evacuate_Building(self):
    for room in self.rooms:
        room.Evacuate_Room()
```

But what if you detect that a `Room` is on fire, and therefore you need to evacuate the whole `Building` that `Room` is in, including all of the rooms? Simple: you evacuate the `Room`'s `building` attribute:

```
if is_on_fire(room):
    room.building.Evacutate_Building()
```

---

<sub>1. That's what inheritance means: `class Room(Building):` says that any `Room` is a `Building`. Or, put another way: any code that wants a `Building` and gets a `Room` will be happy with it. Sometimes there are reasons to subvert that meaning (e.g., a mixin class is just a hunk of method implementations; if you write `class Skyscraper(Building, MajorConstructionMixin):`, you're not really declaring that a `Skyscraper` is a `MajorConstructionMixin` because that doesn't really mean anything; you're just borrowing some convenient implementation code)—but that's still the meaning you're subverting.</sub>

<sub>2. Be aware that if you add references in both directions, you have a reference cycle. This isn't illegal, or even usually a problem; it just means that when you abandon a building and all of its rooms, the CPython garbage collector won't find them and delete them immediately, until the next run of the collector. Still, while it's not a big deal, most programs don't need relationships in both directions, so you should see if you can simplify your design by eliminating one.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

A `Room` is not a `Building` ==> `Room` should not be a subclass of `Building`.
A `Building` has many `Room` ==> use composition.

One possible approach is to have each `Building` have a collection of `Room`

```
class Building:
    def __init__(self, name, location):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.rooms = []            # or a set as in @Abamert's reply
                                   # or dict if you want to address it by floor and number, maybe?
    def add_room(self, room):
        self.rooms.append(room)

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, model):
        self.name = roomName
        self.model = model
```

You could also, maybe, have rooms hold a reference to the building they are located in; this reference could be an attribute assigned upon adding a room to a building:

```
class Building:
    ...
    def add_room(self, room):
        room.bldg = self
        self.rooms.append(room)
```

Answer (score -1):

Although I realize this is an old question, I think the main issue of inheritance from instance over class merits attention.

I'm not sure if the previous answers fully understood your example of the importance of inheritance from an instance, where features cannot be detailed in advance, which by definition is required with classes.

In another issue I found an answer describing [the module Acquisition](https://pypi.org/project/Acquisition/#acquiring-from-context) which did exactly this, inheriting from an instance. It might be worth a look: [Inheriting from instance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081253/inheriting-from-instance-in-python)