# How to inherit from pre-existing class instance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I have a class `Parent`:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
```

I then have another class `Child` which extends `Parent`. But I want `Child` to take a pre-existing instance of `parent` and use this as the parent to inherit from (instead of creating a new instance of `Parent` with the same constructor parameters).

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_instance):
        """ Do something with parent_instance to set this as the parent instance """

    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo
```

Then I would ideally be able to do:

```
p = Parent("bar")
c = Child(p)

print(c.get_foo()) # prints "bar"
```

Comment: `self.parent = parent_instance` and then `self.parent.foo` or something similar?

Comment: @KlausD. Could do, but would prefer proper inheritance, if possible. At the moment your suggestion is what I am doing.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the ancient question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081253/inheriting-from-instance-in-python The suggestions still make sense :)

Comment: In your example `"bar"` can't get anything else than an instance attribute. But you can only inherit class attributes.

Answer (score 7):

You could copy the content of the parents's `__dict__` to the child's. You can use `vars()` builtin function to do so, and the dictionary's `update()` method.

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, parent_instance):
        vars(self).update(vars(parent_instance))

    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo


p = Parent("bar")
c = Child(p)

print(c.get_foo())
# prints "bar"
```

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to this?

Comment: Not really, unless you don't want the child to have some specifics attributes that the parent has.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own constructor - provide a classmethod that takes an instance of a parent.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class Child(Parent):
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.foo

    @classmethod
    def from_parent(cls, parent_instance):
        return cls(parent_instance.foo)


p = Parent('bar')
c = Child.from_parent(p)
c.get_foo()
```

Comment: But this will create a new instance of `Parent`, right? I do not want to re-instantiate.

Comment: If foo attribute is changed in the parent class, the link will be break in child. (child will keep the older reference)
e.g : 

    p = Parent("foo");
    c = Child.from_parent(p);
    p.foo = "spam";
    assert c.foo == "foo"

Answer (score 0):

Using `getattr()` to fetch the attribute from the parent instance

```
class Parent: 
    def __init__(self, foo): 
        self.foo = foo 

class Child(Parent): 
    def __init__(self, parent_instance): 
        self.parent_instance = parent_instance
    
    def get_foo(self): 
        return self.foo 
        
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.parent_instance, attr)

par = Parent("bar") 
ch = Child(par)
print(ch.get_foo())
#prints bar
```

Comment: I think this will create a new instance of `Parent` though - I want to use the already existing instance of `Parent` that has been passed in.

Comment: This will crash if you attach another attribute in parent instance that is not in the init signature. Or if instance attribute is renamed, e.g `self._foo = foo`

Comment: I've updated my code to work without creating another instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure inheritance is the right solution here as it breaks the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) in the `__init__` method.

Maybe parents and children just share a common interface.
I'd prefer something like (python3.8):

```python
from typing import Protocol
    
class FoeAware(Protocol):
    @property
    def foe(self):
        ...
 
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, foe):
        self._foe = foe
   
    @property
    def foe(self):
        return self._foe

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent: FoeAware):
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def foe(self):
        return self.parent.foe

p = Parent("bar")
c = Child(p)
c.foe  # bar
```

The key point is that it takes advantage of polymorphism with a common interface `FoeAware`, which is preferable to an inheritance tree.